# Map snapshot to be displayed in notification BigView

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-notifications

In my app, I have location related notifications being received through a Broadcast Receiver.

I would like to display a map inside the notification bigview layout. It would be similar to what is displayed for screenshots, but with a map instead.

Is it possible to initialize a GoogleMap outside of an activity, so I can call the GoogleMap.snapshot method, and place the snapshot in the notification?
I am dispatching the notifications from a Broadcast Receiver, so I have no access to UI elements, such as the fragmentManager.

Comment: [Google Maps Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite) is what comes closest, but unfortunately still requires a custom view (which you cannot put in your notification). You may still be able to get it to work using off-screen rendering and such, but that'll take some trial and error. An alternative that will definitely work is [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/), which just serves images based on your request. That image can then easily be added into a notification. Just be aware there are usage limits.

Comment: @MH. I ended up using google static maps.

Comment: Probably the best option. Glad to hear it worked out.